# IntelliJ CheckerFramework plugin

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, annotations, intellij-14

I use the dependency for the CheckerFramework in Java for a Spring application

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>checker-qual</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

in a Maven project under IntelliJ. I installed the plugin for IntelliJ, available [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7560?pr=phpStorm). However, when I add an annotation, e.g.

import org.checkerframework.checker.igj.qual.ReadOnly;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull;

@Service
public class AService {

```
@Override
public void addSomething(final int[] @NonNull  @ReadOnly something) {}
```

I get the message `Annotations are not allowed here` and I cannot compile. I already turned on all the annotations for the plugin.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you have written is not legal Java.

Annotations on the array type are written before the array brackets, not after them.

If you wish to indicate that `something` is a non-null array of ints, then don't write `int[] @NonNull something`.  Instead, write it like this:

```
int @NonNull [] something
```